# Extract props type from React component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to understand how (and if it's possible) to extract the props type from a given component.

```
const Component = (props: { color: string }) => <div {...props} />;

type ComponentProps = $ExtractArguments<typeof Component>[0] // pseudo-code
```

I found this utility googling, but I don't understand if it can be useful...

```
type $Arguments<F> = $Call<<A: $ReadOnlyArray<mixed>>((...A) => mixed) => A, F>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for React.ElementProps or React.ElementConfig. The last takes into account `defaultProps`, so it's more useful in practice.

[Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementprops)

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQduEAdqvAMImTNbPwC8cABRhiYVAC44AbzhMANtClsowZgHM4AXwCUcfgD44AHgAmwAG4yAdLdERxWuAHoD9OjACeYLHAAKYuiC2Hgw1gCi8lggvDCczATA6sZePhAEcJzgLLFuDFHwTFCU+AEOkv6B+jJyEIpQUmRk2vQFcADuxBpl4lI9QTUKSnAAjC1AA)

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Component = (props: { color: string }) => <div {...props} />;

type Props = React.ElementConfig<typeof Component>;
```